# When trying to filter out posts by users that aren't in a many to many field ran into error 'method' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

So when I try to filter out certain posts in a twitter like application I cannot seem to loop over the many to many field to display the posts.
This is the code that is giving me trouble:

`posts1 = Post.objects.filter(user__username__in=request.user.following.all)`

I need to call this for my pagination otherwise I could've just done this all inside my template.

These are the models I use in this call:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    follower = models.ManyToManyField("User", related_name="followers", blank=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField("User", related_name="follow", blank=True)
    

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="users")
    post = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    like = models.IntegerField()

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "user": self.user,
            "post": self.post,
            "timestamp": self.timestamp.strftime("%b %-d %Y, %-I:%M %p"),
            "like": self.like,
        }
```

Comment: seems it was a typo, perhaps  `request.user.following.all()` instead `request.user.following.all` ?

Comment: Not a typo because even though it doesn't produce an error it doesn't display any messages. The user I tried it on follows 2 users.

Comment: Then what do you mean by the title of this question?

Comment: Most of the threads I've looked through do not have the it as a function so maybe it is somethings else

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my error by changing it to
`posts1 = Post.objects.filter(user__in=request.user.following.all())`